# How to return a list as frozenset type?

Tags: python, frozenset

I wants to return a list as frozenset type and its type will be checked by returning function as given below

```
frozentSet = functionName(list1, list2)

if type(frozentSet) == frozenset:
    print("Return value is a frozenset")
else:
    print("Retrun value is not a frozenset")
```

Whenever I am returning any list as "frozenset" it gives the result as below, while I wants to return as given in above if condition.

```
return frozenset(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])

Output:
['f']
['b']
['a']
['d']
['e']
Returned value is not a frozenset
```

Thanks for your prompt response. Please see the whole code below.

```
def returnFrozenset(listA):
    frsA = frozenset(listA)
    return frsA
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   lst1_count = int(input().strip())
   lst1 = []

for _ in range(lst1_count):
    lst1_item = input()
    lst1.append(lst1_item)

   isFrozenSet = returnFrozenset(lst1)
   print("Returned value is {1} frozenset".format(isFrozenSet, "a" if type(frset) == frozenset else "not a"))
```

Comment: No, the code you’ve posted definitely works (though the type check is better performed using `isinstance`). Please post the *actual code* that’s failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a little more code we can help you out, I'm doing the same as you and everything is working fine.

Example code:

```py
def func(list1):
    return frozenset(list1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    frozentSet = func(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
    if type(frozentSet) == frozenset:
        print("Return value is a frozenset")
    else:
        print("Retrun value is not a frozenset")
```

output:

```sh
>> frozenset({'a', 'd', 'b', 'f', 'e', 'c'})
>> Return value is a frozenset
```

Comment: I think there's no point in doing that. The function either succeeds and returns a `frozenset` object or raises an exception due to an unhashable type. That is, the function itself should be enough. You could also catch the exception and this way be sure that the object is not a `frozenset` ( if you explicitly need to know that)

Comment: I know that it's just to show him that the amount of code that he provided us isn't enough to fix his issue since I'm using his same code and everything works fine and giving him an example of it working

Comment: I have added the complete code in below of my Main code.